Doubt on Neukirch ANT $(3.1)$ theorem .
On the page 17 of neukirch ANT i have a doubt in the proof

The ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ is noetherian, integrally closed, and every prime ideal $\mathcal{p}\neq0$ is a maximal ideal

In the proof while prooving prime ideal is maximal. He writes

Now $\mathcal{p}\cap \mathbb{Z}$ is non zero prime ideal  $<p>$ in integers and primality in $\mathbb{Z}$ and if $y\in\mathcal{p}$ and $y\neq 0$. and $$y^n+a_1 y^{n-1}+...=a_n=0$$
is an equation for $y$ with $a_j\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a_n\in \mathcal{p}\cap \mathbb{Z}$

and the integral domain $\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{O}_K/\mathcal{p}$ arise from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ by adjoing algeraic element therefore field.
Questions
where the fact is used $$y^n+a_1 y^{n-1}+...=a_n=0$$
is an equation for $y$ with $a_j\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a_n\in\mathcal{p}\cap \mathbb{Z}$
why $\mathcal{O}$ arises by adjoining algebraic elements.

Here are the underlying details of the proof. In order to show that $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ is maximal, Neukirch shows that $\mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{p}$ is a field, by showing that this last ring is obtained as an algebraic extension of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some prime number $p$.
To do so, he first argues that there exists a prime number $p \in \Bbb Z$ such that $\mathfrak{p} \cap \Bbb Z = p \Bbb Z$. Indeed, $\mathfrak{p} \cap \Bbb Z$ is a prime ideal of $\Bbb Z$, and it remains to show that this is not the trivial prime $(0)$ (which implies that it MUST be of the form $p \Bbb Z$ for some prime number $p$). So we want to find a nonzero element of $\mathfrak{p} \cap \Bbb Z$.
If we pick any $y \in \mathfrak{p}$, there is a minimal vanishing polynomial for $y$ with integer coefficients:
$$y^n+a_1 y^{n-1}+...+a_n=0$$
and by minimality of the degree, we have in particular that $a_n \neq 0$ (otherwise we could factor out a $y$ and find a lower degree polynomial). If you isolate $a_n$, you see that it is a sum of multiples of $y$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, hence $a_n \in \mathfrak{p}$. This shows that $a_n$ is a nonzero element of $\mathfrak{p} \cap \Bbb Z$, which is what we wanted to show.
Now, the inclusion $\Bbb Z \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_K$ induces a map
$$\Bbb Z / (\mathfrak{p} \cap \Bbb Z) = \Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z = \Bbb F_p \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{p}.$$
Recall moreover that $\mathcal{O}_K$ was obtained from $\Bbb Z$ by adding algebraic elements, which shows that $\mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{p}$ is obtained from $\Bbb F_p$ by adding the same algebraic elements (or rather, adding their images in the quotient $\mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{p}$, which are still algebraic over $\Bbb F_p$ by reducing the original polynomial mod $p$). But a ring obtained by adding algebraic elements to a field is again a field, which concludes that $\mathcal{O}_K / \mathfrak{p}$ is a field.
